# A way to replace a shortcut with an absolute path in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shortcut

I have a program that needs to be provided with an **absolute path** to a particular file - call it `xfile` located at `/home/user/.hidden/sub/sub2/xfile`

Is there a way to make some sort of replacement function whereby I would type `xfile`, press `TAB` and have it replaced by the absolute path?

I've tried creating an alias and exporting it under `~/.profile` but the program hasn't liked it so far.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash, then add the following line into your ~/.bashrc

```
export xfile="/home/user/.hidden/sub/sub2/xfile";
```

Logout, login again, and then use it by calling:

```
your_program $xfile
```

The only difference, instead of typing *tab* you type *$*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know solution for completing relative path to absolute path but you can write something like that in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`instead of alias.

```sh
function your_program()
{
    /path/to/your_program $PWD/$1
}
```